# Save Files pointed by URL to AWS S3

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wget

I have a set of URL's in a text file. These URL's point to some pdf, doc, HTML or txt files. I want to save these files on AWS S3 without having to download the file on local system and then pushing it to s3.(Preferably python or bash script).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. S3 only accepts content, not URLs to download. However, there are a number of options to usr other low cost AWS services to do the downloading/uploading for you.

Consider creating a Lambda that accepts a URL and downloads that URL, then uploads it to S3. You could run a script that loops through the lines of the file, and triggers a Lambda for each line (watch out for the lambda concurrent run limit).

The code for that lambda would be very simple in Node.js using the Request library